# INSERT EN TABLA REMOTA A PARTIR DE TABLA LOCAL POSTGRESQL

Tags: postgresql-9.3

usando postgresql, la siguiente instrucción actualiza una tabla local a partir de una tabla remota:

```
INSERT INTO tblA
    SELECT id, time 
    FROM dblink('dbname=dbtest', 'SELECT id, time FROM tblB')
    AS t(id integer, time integer)
    WHERE time > 1000;
```

Ahora bien, yo necesito lo contrario, a partir de una tabla local, actualizar una tabla que está en un hosting. La base de datos esta en  postgresql.
Alguien me podría colaborar con un ejemplo o indicarme cómo hacerlo?
De antemano muchas gracias por su colaboración.

Toledano, adjunto toda la función para mejor comprensión de lo necesito hacer. La tabla a la que le debo hacer el insert, está en un hosting

```
SELECT dblink_connect('miconexion'
       ,'hostaddr=185.15.999.9 port=11076 dbname=axio user=webadmin password=xxXXxxXX');

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION edgar() RETURNS SETOF tabxter AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    nit varchar;
    nom varchar;
    reg tabxter%rowtype;
BEGIN
    RAISE NOTICE 'mensaje--------------------------';
    FOR reg IN
       SELECT "TERCXNIT","TERCNOMB" FROM public.tabxter a
    LOOP
      RETURN NEXT reg; -- return current row of SELECT
      nit  = reg."TERCXNIT";
      Xnit = reg."TERCXNIT";
      nom  = reg."TERCNOMB";
      RAISE NOTICE 'mensaje 9 %,%',nit,reg."TERCNOMB";
      PERFORM dblink_exec('miconexion','***INSERT INTO public.tabxter("TERCXNIT") VALUES(nit)***');
    END LOOP;
END
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT * FROM edgar();
```

IGUALMENTE ADJUNTO PANTALLAZO DE LA FUNCIÓN para mejor apreciación
[image: FUNCION]

Comment: Lo que quieres hacer no es lo contrario, es lo mismo. Consulta la documentación de `dblink()`. Solo te falta especificar la cadena de conexión: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/libpq-connect.html

Comment: Muy amable toledano por su comentario. Soy nuevo en estas lides del postgresql. 
La cadena de conexión que tengo es esta:
SELECT dblink_connect('miconexion'
       ,'hostaddr=190.158.XXX.XXX  port=5432 dbname=axio user=postgres password=clave')

Sin embargo sigo un poco perdido. Qué mas debo hacer? Qué me falta parametrizar?

Comment: Inténtalo y verás que falta. Si ya lo intentaste y obtuviste un error, __edita__ tu pregunta para agregar esos detalles.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que realizar las consultas necesarias para obtener los datos que deseas registrar y concatenarlos a la consulta de tu db link

```
select dblink('host=xxx.xxx.xx.xx dbname=database user=postgres password=postgres port=5432 ', 'insert into tp_table (field) values(''||(select field from tp_table_local where id=1)||'')')
```